# Calling a class placed in the def of another class | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

I'm writing a bot for discord. I'm using the nextcord library. When I wanted to add a command to @bot.event to make the buttons in commands etc not fade out after restarting the bot I encountered a strange problem. Well, I have all the files scattered with each other in different folders although this is not important. The most important thing is that the class (which is responsible for the button) is placed in a very strange place from which I do not know how to call it....

Here I send the code of the main file, where the bot event is supposed to be:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as', bot.user)
    bot.statuses = cycle([f'{status_1}', f'{status_2}', f'{status_3}'])
    change_status.start()
    bot.add_view() # In these brackets is supposed to be this class
```

Here I submit the code of the file where the button command is located:

```
class Class(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @application_checks.is_owner()
    @nextcord.slash_command(name="example_command", description="example_command")
    async def example_test(self, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        class Button(nextcord.ui.View):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__(timeout=None)

            @nextcord.ui.button(label="Click it", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple, disabled=False,
                                custom_id="Click it")
            async def number_button(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction,
                                    ):
                await interaction.send("message")

        await interaction.send("example", view=Button())


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Class(bot))
```

Please help :(

I have already tried importing the file and this class: "Button" by typing:

```
Class().Button()
```

But it didn't work. My guess is that it doesn't work because of where it is

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to have the class inside a function. Move the button class outside of the function into top-level and you should be able to use it there.

Comment: A class defined inside a function is like any other local variable. If it's not returned by the function, there's no way to access it from outside.